# How to anchor a point to another objects point for animation?

Tags: animation, shape-keys

I'm trying to animate 2 objects which are essentially 1 when combined. There is 1 point on the "parent" object which needs to follow or be "anchored" to another point on the second object and needs to stay anchored to this point throughout an animation. Is it possible to anchor one point to another throughout an animation without merging points? Below is an image showing a point that follows another, but I would like it to be anchored to this point. how should I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

that's the perfect use case for the "child of" object constraint.

you can use "influence" to set it "on" and "off".

[image]